# Invalid index error in a for loop

Tags: scilab

I've been working in this code for a while, it's pretty simple, just recursive calculation. At the while loop, in the first line I got an index error. Funny thing is before I start using the if statement in loop my index was fine and I could compile it. My believe my problem is the lack of familiarity with the scilab way of programming.

```
///CONSTANTES////

roh_H20 = 1030.00 // [kg/m^3] Água Salgada
roh_ar = 1.22 // [kg/m^3]
g = 9.81 // [m/s^2]

V_elo = 0.00041 // [m^3] 
V_boia = 0.00811 // [m^3] 
V_lastro = 0.00811 // [m^3]

D_corda = 0.030 // [m]
A_corda = 1/4*%pi*D_corda**2
L_corda = 30 // [m]
roh_corda = 905 // [kg/m^3]  poliester
V_corda = A_corda*L_corda // [m^3]

roh_elo = 952 // [kg/m^3] PE Alta Densidade


m_elo = 0.38817 // [kg] 
m_boia = 1.5654 // [Kg] 
m_lastro = 2.5 // [kg] CHUTE
m_corda = roh_corda*V_corda; // [kg]

Cd = 1.3 // coeficiente de arrasto placa plana FOX pg 396

N_elo = 7*24 // conjuntos a cada 1 metro
N_corda = 4 // A definir
N_boia = 7  // 2 primeiros conjuntos   
N_lastro = 7 // 2 últimos conjuntos

/// PROBLEMA ESTATICO ////

M = N_elo*m_elo + N_boia*(m_boia + m_lastro) // FALTA CORDA
P = M*g
Emp = g*(N_boia*V_boia + N_elo*V_elo + N_lastro*V_lastro)*roh_H20;

printf("\n*****PROBLEMA ESTATICO*****\n")
printf("\nO Peso do conjunto eh: %f N\n", P)
printf("\nO Empuxo eh: %f N\n", Emp)


/// PROBLEMA DINÂMICO ///

A_vela = 0.03230 // [m^2] dado pelo SolidWorks
N_vela = 7

printf("\n*****PROBLEMA DINAMICO*****\n")

a = zeros(0,1e3)
a(1)= (Emp-P)/ M
printf("\na_0 = %f [m/s^2]\n", a(1))

t=0
v= zeros(0,1e3)
dy = zeros(0,1e3)
Fd = zeros(0,1e3)


for i=1:50
//    if i == 1 then
//      a(i)= (Emp-P)/ M  
//    else 
//      1+1
//     end      
    v(i+1) = v(i) + a(i)*t
    dy(i+1) =  dy(i)+v(i+1)*t+ a(i)*t*t/2.0
    Fd(i+1) = 0.5*roh_H20*Cd*N_vela*A_vela*v(i+1)**2
    if v(i+1) > 0 then       
        a(i+1) = (Emp - P - Fd(i+1))/ M;
    elseif v(i+1) <= 0 then       
        a(i+1) = (Emp - P + Fd(i+1))/ M;
    end,        
t=t+0.05
end


x = linspace(0,t,int(i))

// Grafico velocidade/aceleração

clf(0)
scf(0)
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x,a,'ro-')
xlabel("Tempo [s]")
ylabel("Acelaração [m/s^2]")
legend("aceleração")

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x,v,'bs:')
xlabel("Tempo [s]")
ylabel("velocidade [m/s]")
legend("velocidade")

// Grafico forca/deslocamento

clf(1)
scf(1)
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x,Fd,'r--d')
xlabel("Tempo [s]")
ylabel("Força [N]")
legend("Força Arrasto")

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x,dy,'m--^')
xlabel("Tempo [s]")
ylabel("Descolcamento [m]")
legend("deslocamento")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that the code snippets are for JavaScript/HTML only, they do not work for other languages.  Also, when adding tags please check their meaning (shown in the popup-up): for example, "indexing" tag does not mean what you think it means. And there is no recursion in your code at all.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have index error, there are two things to do in the console:

1. Check the value of the index variable (just by entering its name)
2. Check the size(s) of any arrays involved (using the command `size`)

In this case, checking the size of `a` would show it's not what you expected it to be. Why?  Because of this:

```
a = zeros(0,1e3)
v= zeros(0,1e3)
dy = zeros(0,1e3)
Fd = zeros(0,1e3)
```

The arguments of `zeros` are the height and width of a matrix. You are asking for height 0... this means **empty** matrix, since it has no rows. What you want is a row vector, which is a matrix with **one** row.

After fixing this you'll run into a problem with

```
x = linspace(0,t,int(i))
plot(x,a,'ro-')
```

because x and a are not of the same size.

To keep sizes consistent, you could do something like this:

```
imax = 50;
a = zeros(1,imax)
v= zeros(1,imax)
dy = zeros(1,imax)
Fd = zeros(1,imax)
```

and later `for i=1:imax`  and `x = linspace(0,t,imax)`.

This way you are not creating oversized arrays, but only arrays of the size you want, which can be adjusted by changing the value of imax.